# Grab Public IP Of a New Running Instance and send it via SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So, I have this code, and I will love to grab the public IP address of the new windows instance that will be created when I adjust the desired capacity.
The launch template assigns an automatic tag name when I adjust the desired_capacity. I want to be able to grab the public IP address of that tag name.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('autoscaling')


def set_desired_capacity(asg_name, desired_capacity):
    response = client.set_desired_capacity(
        AutoScalingGroupName=asg_name,
        DesiredCapacity=desired_capacity,
    )
    return response


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    asg_name = "test"
    desired_capacity = 1
    return set_desired_capacity(asg_name, desired_capacity)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(lambda_handler("", ""))
```

I took a look at the EC2 client documentation, and I wasn't sure what to use. I just need help modifying my code

Comment: Please note that it can take some time (maybe even a few minutes) for a new instance to be launched after changing the desired capacity (and even longer to get a Public IP address). Your code would need to search for all instances in the Auto Scaling group and then detect when the new instance is available. This could take several calls to `describe_instances()` until the information is available. An alternate approach is to have the instance itself retrieve its own IP address through a User Data script that runs when the instance launches.

Comment: Can this user data script send the result to an SNS topic?

Comment: Sure! It can use the AWS CLI `aws sns publish` [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html), or if you write it in Python then it would use the boto3 [`publish()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) command. The script can discover its own Instance ID by retrieving [Instance metadata and user data - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) and then call `aws ec2 describe-instances` to retrieve the IP address.

Comment: If it's not much trouble, can you write this alternative script as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tag that you are assigning in the autoscaling group, then you can just use a `describe_instances` method. The [Boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) have an example with filtering. Something like this should work, replacing `TAG`, `VALUE`, and `TOPICARN` with the appropriate values.

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', 'us-west-2')
sns_client = boto3.client('sns', 'us-west-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
Filters=[
    {
        'Name': 'tag:TAG',
        'Values': [
            'VALUE'
        ]
    }
]
)

for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        ip = instance["PublicIpAddress"]
        sns_publish = sns_client.publish(
            TopicArn='TOPICARN',
            Message=ip,
        )
        print(sns_publish)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I even tried only the code after the instance is fully running, yet, it didn't work.

Comment: What didn’t work? Did you receive an error that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Objective:

- After an EC2 instance starts
- Obtain the IP address
- Send a message via Amazon SNS

It can take some time for a Public IP address to be assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance. Rather than continually calling `DescribeInstances()`, it would be easier to [Run commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) via a User Data script.

The script could:

- Obtain its Public IP address via [Instance metadata and user data - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

```
IP=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)
```

- Send a message to an Amazon SNS topic with:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn xxx  --message $IP
```

If you also want the message to **include a name from a tag** associated with the instance, the script will need to call `aws ec2 describe-instances` with its own Instance ID (which can be obtained via the Instance Metadata) and then extra the name from the `tags` returned.

Comment: Hi John, it's a windows instance. I need to update the question